# Joining series of dates and counting continous days

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have a table as below

```
date        add_days
2015-01-01  5
2015-01-04  2
2015-01-11  7
2015-01-20  10
2015-01-30  1
```

what I want to do is to check the `days_balance`, i.e. if `date` is greater or smaller than previous date + N days (`add_days`) and take the cumulated sum of days count if they are a continuous series.

So the algorithm should work like

```
for i in 2:N_rows {
   days_balance[i] := date[i-1] + add_days[i-1] - date[i]
   if days_balance[i] >= 0 then
      date[i] := date[i] + days_balance[i]
}
```

The expected result should be as follows

```
date        days_balance
2015-01-01  0
2015-01-04  2
2015-01-11  -3
2015-01-20  -2
2015-01-30  0
```

Is it possible in pure SQL? I imagine it *should* be with some conditional joins, but cannot see how it could be implemented.

Comment: If you are using PostgreSQL 9.1.13 or above, you need to look into `lag` and `lead` window functions in PostgresSQL. Also, how do you calculate previous_date and previous_add_days for your first record?

Comment: @FutbolFan by current and previous dates I mean the subsequent rows - I'll edit for clarity.

Comment: Yes, I got that part. But, for your row  where date = `2015-01-01`, what would be the previous_date and previous_add_days for that record is what I was asking?

Comment: Is the expected result correct? Shouldn't the fourth row be -5? Here's my math: 
day 01 to 04 = 0 balance minus 3 days change + 5 add_days = 2; 
day 04 to 11 = 2 balance minus 7 days change + 2 add_days = -3; 
day 11 to 20 = -3 balance minus 9 days change + 7 add_days = -5;
day 20 to 30 = -5 balance minus 10 days change + 10 add_days = -5;

Comment: @FutbolFan I updated my question and pseudocode - is it clear now?

Comment: @Anssssss forth row should be 11+7-20 = -2 since 4th and 5th rows are <0.

Comment: @Tim I think Anssssss is very close to solving your issue.  So, I think it's probably best to let him finish this one.

Comment: @Tim I still don't quite understand the math, but it sounds like it is a conditional addition (don't add in some value if the previous days_balance was 0 or something). If that's the case then I don't think my "normal join" solution will help you, but I do think the "recursive CTE" solution will work with some slight change like a CASE statement in the math or something...can you make that edit yourself or at least post what you think it is?

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting another answer since it may be nice to compare them since they use different methods (this one just does a n^2 style join, other one used a recursive CTE). This one takes advantage of the fact that you don't have to calculate the days_balance for each previous row before calculating it for a particular row, you just need to sum things from previous days....

```
drop table junk
create table junk(date DATETIME, add_days int)

insert into junk values
('2015-01-01',5  ),       
('2015-01-04',2  ),      
('2015-01-11',7  ),      
('2015-01-20',10 ),      
('2015-01-30',1  )    

;WITH cte as
(
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date) i, date, add_days, ISNULL(DATEDIFF(DAY, LAG(date) OVER (ORDER BY date), date), 0) days_since_prev
    FROM Junk
)
, combinedWithAllPreviousDaysCte as
(
    select i [curr_i], date [curr_date], add_days [curr_add_days], days_since_prev [curr_days_since_prev], 0 [prev_add_days], 0 [prev_days_since_prev] from cte where i = 1 --get first row explicitly since it has no preceding rows
    UNION ALL
    select curr.i [curr_i], curr.date [curr_date], curr.add_days [curr_add_days], curr.days_since_prev [curr_days_since_prev], prev.add_days [prev_add_days], prev.days_since_prev [prev_days_since_prev]
    from cte curr 
    join cte prev on curr.i > prev.i --join to all previous days
)
select curr_i, curr_date, SUM(prev_add_days) - curr_days_since_prev - SUM(prev_days_since_prev) [days_balance]
from combinedWithAllPreviousDaysCte
group by curr_i, curr_date, curr_days_since_prev
order by curr_i
```

outputs:

```
+--------+-------------------------+--------------+
| curr_i |        curr_date        | days_balance |
+--------+-------------------------+--------------+
|      1 | 2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 |            0 |
|      2 | 2015-01-04 00:00:00.000 |            2 |
|      3 | 2015-01-11 00:00:00.000 |           -3 |
|      4 | 2015-01-20 00:00:00.000 |           -5 |
|      5 | 2015-01-30 00:00:00.000 |           -5 |
+--------+-------------------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think I have it with a recursive CTE (sorry, I only have Microsoft SQL Server available to me at the moment, so it may not comply with PostgreSQL).

Also I think the expected results you had were off (see comment above). If not, this can probably be modified to conform to your math.

```
drop table junk
create table junk(date DATETIME, add_days int)

insert into junk values
('2015-01-01',5  ),       
('2015-01-04',2  ),      
('2015-01-11',7  ),      
('2015-01-20',10 ),      
('2015-01-30',1  )    

;WITH cte as
(
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date) i, date, add_days, ISNULL(DATEDIFF(DAY, LAG(date) OVER (ORDER BY date), date), 0) days_since_prev
    FROM Junk
)
,recursiveCte (i, date, add_days, days_since_prev, days_balance, math)  as
(
    select top 1 
        i, 
        date, 
        add_days, 
        days_since_prev, 
        0 [days_balance], 
        CAST('no math for initial one, just has zero balance' as varchar(max)) [math]
    from cte where i = 1
    UNION ALL --recursive step now
    select 
        curr.i, 
        curr.date, 
        curr.add_days, 
        curr.days_since_prev, 
        prev.days_balance - curr.days_since_prev + prev.add_days [days_balance],
        CAST(prev.days_balance as varchar(max)) + ' - ' + CAST(curr.days_since_prev as varchar(max)) + ' + ' + CAST(prev.add_days as varchar(max)) [math]
    from cte curr
    JOIN recursiveCte prev ON curr.i = prev.i + 1       
)
select i,  DATEPART(day,date) [day], add_days, days_since_prev, days_balance, math
from recursiveCTE
order by date
```

And the results are like so:

```
+---+-----+----------+-----------------+--------------+------------------------------------------------+
| i | day | add_days | days_since_prev | days_balance | math                                           |
+---+-----+----------+-----------------+--------------+------------------------------------------------+
| 1 | 1   | 5        | 0               | 0            | no math for initial one, just has zero balance |
| 2 | 4   | 2        | 3               | 2            | 0 - 3 + 5                                      |
| 3 | 11  | 7        | 7               | -3           | 2 - 7 + 2                                      |
| 4 | 20  | 10       | 9               | -5           | -3 - 9 + 7                                     |
| 5 | 30  | 1        | 10              | -5           | -5 - 10 + 10                                   |
+---+-----+----------+-----------------+--------------+------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Also, I don't feel like this is a great solution since the recursion level increases with each row, so it probably would be better/more efficient to just use something to iteratively process the results (but the original question was not asking for that).

Answer (score -1):

I don’t quite get how your algorithm returns your expected results?  But let me share a technique I came up with that might help.

This will only work if the end result of your data is to be exported to Excel, and even then it won’t work in all scenarios depending on what format you export your dataset in, but here it is....

If you’ll familiar with Excel Formulas, what I discovered is that if you write an Excel formula in your SQL as another field, it will execute that formula for you as soon as you export to excel (best method that works for me is just coping and pasting it into Excel, so that it doesn’t format it as text)

So for your example, here’s what you could do (noting again I don’t understand your algorithm, so this is probably wrong, but it’s just to give you the concept)

```
SELECT
    date
  , add_days
  , '=INDEX($1:$65536,ROW()-1,COLUMN()-2)'
  ||'+INDEX($1:$65536,ROW()-1,COLUMN()-1)'
  ||'-INDEX($1:$65536,ROW(),COLUMN()-2)'
    AS "days_balance[i]"
  ,'=IF(INDEX($1:$65536,ROW(),COLUMN()-1)>=0'
  ||',INDEX($1:$65536,ROW(),COLUMN()-3)'
  ||'+INDEX($1:$65536,ROW(),COLUMN()-1))'
    AS "date[i]"
FROM
  myTable
ORDER BY /*Ensure to order by whatever you need for your formula to work*/
```

The key part to making this work is using the `INDEX` formula function to select a cell based on the position of the current cell.  So `ROW()-1`  tells it get me the result of the previous record, and `COLUMN()-2` means take the value from two columns to the left of the current.  Because you can't use cell references like `A2+B2-A3` because the row numbers won't change on export, and it assumes the position of the columns.

I used SQL string concatenation with `||` just so it's easier to read on screen.

I tried this one in excel; it didn’t match your expected results.  But if this technique works for you then just correct the excel formula to suit.